# How to fix OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science, timedelta

I'm trying to subtract column `df['date_of_admission']` from the column `df['DOB']` to find the difference between then and store the age value in `df['age']` column, however, I'm getting this error:

> OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition

```
 DOB          date_of_admission      age
 2000-05-07   2019-01-19 12:26:00        
 1965-01-30   2019-03-21 02:23:12        
 NaT          2018-11-02 18:30:10        
 1981-05-01   2019-05-08 12:26:00       
 1957-01-10   2018-12-31 04:01:15         
 1968-07-14   2019-01-28 15:05:09            
 NaT          2018-04-13 06:20:01 
 NaT          2019-02-15 01:01:57 
 2001-02-10   2019-03-21 08:22:00       
 1990-03-29   2018-11-29 03:05:03
.....         ......
.....         .....
.....         .....
```

I've tried it with the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import dt

df['age'] = (df['date_of_admission'] - df['DOB']).dt.days // 365
```

Expected to get the following age column after finding the difference between:

```
age
26
69
NaN
58
.
.
.
```

Comment: how python knows it is date?

Comment: You are doing it correctly but the `DOB` contains the only date AND `date_of_admission` contains both date and time. Manipulate the `date_of_admission` so that it will only contain the date, then you will get your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert both columns into date then subtract it

```
import pandas as pd


df['date_of_admission'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_admission']).dt.date

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.date

df['age'] = ((df['date_of_admission']-df['DOB']).dt.days) //365
```

**SECOND TEST**

```
#Now I have use DOB AND date_of_admission data from the question and it is working fine

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"DOB":['2000-05-07','1965-01-30','NaT'],
                   "date_of_admission":["2019-01-19 12:26:00","2019-03-21 02:23:12", "2018-11-02 18:30:10"]})

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.date
df['date_of_admission'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_admission']).dt.date
df['age'] = ((df['date_of_admission']-df['DOB']).dt.days) //365
```

RESULT:

```
DOB       date_of_admission   age
2000-05-07  2019-01-19       18.0
1965-01-30  2019-03-21       54.0
NaT         2018-11-02       NaN
```

Comment: Hi tawab, thank you for the kind assistance.

I tried it, and i was able to get age as following format:
0         23714 days, 0:00:00
1         25980 days, 0:00:00
2         25980 days, 0:00:00
3         14250 days, 0:00:00

Now I tried df['age'] = ((df['date_of_admission']-df['DOB']).dt.days) //365
But I got this error:  AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: @bilal first convert them in date format using pd.to_datetime() then tried to subtract

Comment: i tried it as follows:
df[date_of_admission'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_admission'])
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])
df['age'] = ((df['date_of_admission']-df['DOB']).dt.days) //365

and again i come back to the same error:
OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition

Comment: Kindly share the dataframe code,then I can check the issue

Comment: this is the code as requested 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
df['age'] = (df['date_of_admission'] - df['DOB']).dt.days // 365
df['age'] = np.where(df['age'] < 0, 90, df['age'])
df['age'].isnull().sum()

Comment: @bilal now I have created a dataframe using your question data values and it is working fine

Comment: I copied your code it worked perfect. but when I want to apply it on df['date_of_admission'] and df['DOB'] to get the df['age'] then i get this error again:
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

I used this code which created the above error

import pandas as pd
import datetime

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.date
df['date_of_admission'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_admission']).dt.date
df['age'] = ((df['date_of_admission']-df['DOB']).dt.days) //365

Comment: @bilal I think you need to check the values in DOB and date_of_admission I think some values are not date in your actual data

Comment: i will give an example: when i subtract df['date_of_admission'] from df['DOB'] to get df['age'] then i write the following code
df['age'] = df['date_of_admission'] - df['DOB']
And i print the df['age']  and i get the following 

2         25980 days, 0:00:00
3         14250 days, 0:00:00
4         21531 days, 0:00:00
5         26299 days, 0:00:00
6                     0:00:00
7         27168 days, 0:00:00
8        109573 days, 0:00:00
9         26394 days, 0:00:00
 

When I do the following then errors occur
df['age'] = ((df['date_of_admission']-df['DOB']).dt.days) //365

Comment: can you provide the complete data ? so that I can resolve the issue

Comment: can you provide the complete data ? so that I can resolve the issue

Comment: I can show smaple of those columns as I cant share the whole data due to ethics and other restrictions which prevent me sharing the data.

Please see the sample of this data in this link 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N16RFcWtxx7PJ9Aiazx8G3TB6-eVdBbZ/view?usp=sharing

So age is the column which i added based in the substraction between date_of_admission and DOB.

the data type is in second sheet

Answer (score 9):

OP is most likely using the medical MIMIC dataset, where dates have been scrambled to protect the identities of patients. Specifically, for patients over age 89, [they shifted the date of birth by 300 years](https://mimic.physionet.org/mimictables/patients/).

Long timespans such as this give an overflow when using pandas timedelta:

```py
pd.to_timedelta(300, unit="Y", box=False)
> numpy.timedelta64(-8979658473709551616,'ns')
```

When this occurs in a dataframe operation, you'll experience an error instead. As adapted from the answer of @tawab_shakeel :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"DOB":['2000-05-07','1965-01-30','1700-01-01'],
                   "date_of_admission":["2019-01-19 12:26:00","2019-03-21 02:23:12", "2000-01-01 02:23:23"]})

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.date
df['date_of_admission'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_admission']).dt.date

# Gives AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
df['age'] = ((df['date_of_admission']-df['DOB']).dt.days) //365

# Gives OverflowError: long too big to convert
pd.to_timedelta(df['date_of_admission']-df['DOB'])
```

This problem occurs with any calculation that converts to a `timedelta64[ns]` datatype.

As a workaround, you can use an `apply` operation instead, directly calculating the age element per element:

```
df['age'] = df.apply(lambda e: (e['date_of_admission'] - e['DOB']).days/365, axis=1)
```

Comment: It works, but it will make the function a bit slow

Answer (score 1):

1). You are doing it correctly but the `DOB` contains the only date AND `date_of_admission` contains both date and time. Manipulate the `date_of_admission` so that it will only contain the date, then you will get your result.

2). Here I am adding a `change function` into your code so that you will get your result.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import dt

def change(x):
    return x.date()

df['date_of_admission'] = df['date_of_admission'].apply(change)

df['age'] = df['date_of_admission'].subtract(df['DOB']).dt.days // 365
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you Rahul. I tired it but it gave me this error:
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: @bilal The `def change(x)` use this function on `date_of_admission` which is a `datetime.datetime` object. I think you used it on `DOB` which is a `datetime.date` object, this is the reason you are getting this ERROR. I have crossed checked it, it is working on my laptop.

Comment: @bilal `x = datetime.datetime(2019,6,21,3,25,26)
            print(x)
            print(x.date())`  first try this code on your laptop,**AND** then try 'y=datetime.date(2019,5,26)
print(y)
print(y.date)`. CODE, you will see the difference.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, i tried it and i received this error:
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
Although i have imported datetime

Comment: I am uploading a link of the image you can see it there:-   "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1IZY8Kp3jRJqFibNYHGULShKaura2PGNi".    It is working for me.

Comment: @ Rahul charan, the example in the picture worked. but not this one 
df['date_of_admission'] = df['date_of_admission'].apply(change)

df['age'] = (df['date_of_admission'] - df['DOB']).dt.days // 365

when i print either df['date_of_admission'] or df['DOB'] i get normal date: e.g. 1975-10-10   but when i subtract them and divide according to this

df['age'] = (df['date_of_admission'] - df['DOB']).dt.days // 365
then i  come back to the same issue Overflow in int64 addition

Comment: @bilal Make sure that values in the columns `date_of_admission` and `DOB` are of **datetime object type** .  Check the type of column by `print(type(df['DOB'][0]))` AND also `print(type(df['date_of_admission'][0]))` .

Comment: @bilal If they are not datetime object then use `df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.date`   **AND**   `df['date_of_admission'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_admission']).dt.date` . To convert them into datetime object.

Comment: I apply it like this :

import pandas as pd
import datetime

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.date
df['date_of_admission'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_admission']).dt.date
df['age'] = ((df['date_of_admission']-df['DOB']).dt.days) //365

and i received this error:

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: @bilal If your dataset is not so important then upload it on google drive and send the link here so that I can download it and see it, then I may help you out.

Comment: unfortunately I can't share data due to restriction "ethics etc".

so when I print the df['age'] which is:
df['age'] = df['date_of_admission'] - df['DOB']
And i print the df['age']  and i get the following 

2         25980 days, 0:00:00
3         14250 days, 0:00:00
4         21531 days, 0:00:00
5         26299 days, 0:00:00
6                     0:00:00
7         27168 days, 0:00:00
8        109573 days, 0:00:00
9         26394 days, 0:00:00
 

this one still causing the errors
df['age'] = ((df['date_of_admission']-df['DOB']).dt.days) //365

Comment: @bilal it's ok if you can't share your dataset. Check the `type` of values in your `DOB` AND `date_of_admission` columns, if they are of **datetime object** then ERROR should not come.

Comment: I have attaached a sample of the 2 columns in excelsheet in this link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N16RFcWtxx7PJ9Aiazx8G3TB6-eVdBbZ/view?usp=sharing

So age is the column which i added based in the substraction between date_of_admission and DOB.

the data type is in second sheet

Comment: @bilal Bro, now I can give you a solution by using the sample of the dataset which you uploaded.  **Use**  `df['age12'] = df['date_of_admission'].subtract(df['DOB']).dt.days // 365`  to get your result. Initially, I am also getting the same `Overflow in int64 addition` error, after reading full error I led to a solution. If this helps you, please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: I have tried it according to your solution and i'm still getting this error:
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
:( 

This is what I've done:
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.date
df['date_of_admission'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_admission']).dt.date
df['age'] = df['date_of_admission'] - df['DOB']

df['age12'] = df['date_of_admission'].subtract(df['DOB']).dt.days // 365

Comment: @bilal If the dataset is in the format you uploaded here, then only use `import pandas as pd df['age12'] = df['date_of_admission'].subtract(df['DOB']).dt.days // 365`.  **Don not use**  `df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.date df['date_of_admission'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_admission']).dt.date df['age'] = df['date_of_admission'] - df['DOB']`

Comment: @bilal If you use jupyter-notebook then See here https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1L3tw2bCqsihxiO5SaDaUvPz1jAlhEgNG

Comment: @bilal Or you can see here   https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1bl1z4gGWZSjI9W2mqBVkE7qisXmUONH1

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you very much from the jupyter and with your code alone it work fine, but when i run it in my side my code it gives me the same error. 

Well i will try to figure out something. 

Many thanks for your amazing help : )

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked for me.

Based on the answer [here](https://github.com/YerevaNN/mimic3-benchmarks/issues/129#issuecomment-1173475394), try following code:

```
df['AGE'] = df.apply(lambda s: (s['date_of_admission'].to_pydatetime()-s['DOB'].to_pydatetime()).days / 365.0, axis=1)`
```

I should also mention that I used `pandas==1.5`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the MIMIC III dataset and encountered this problem as well. I found that the comment by @Rahul_chacharan to use `df['date_of_admission'].subtract(df['DOB']).dt.days // 365`
worked for me!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30320476)

Answer (score 0):

I think we all meet this problem dealing MIMIC3 database, here is my solution, very intuitive, but much faster, you can have a try.

```
df_labevents_temp['age']  = ((df['date_of_admission'].values  - df['DOB'].values).astype(np.int)/8.64e13//365).astype(np.int)
```

The idea is to turn it to numpy int, then convert from ns to years. The pandas date diff function doesn't work for me, using apply is too slow (I think just loop).

Answer (score 0):

For those getting errors `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values` from @tawab_shakeel's answer, try following code

```py
import pandas as pd

df['date_of_admission'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_admission']).dt.date

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.date

df['age'] = ((df['date_of_admission']-df['DOB']) //365).dt.days
```

It will return int value for age