# How to fix integer Overflow error when substracting datetime objects (using Dask)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dask, integer-overflow

I am doing some data mining on a huge database and using Dask to speed things up (this is important because Dask does not implement ALL pandas methods that could have helped me, like "errors = ignore" in astype).

I am trying to do a substraction between a datetime column and a fixed timestamp. I'm getting an integer overflow error and I'm pretty sure it comes from this sort of date substraction.

I tought of applying .date() to all datetime columns and also to the fixed timestamp I want to substract, but then I get another error (basically I can't substract between DatetimeIndex and Datetime.date). I'm running out of ideas..
The use of Dask makes it way more challenging to find implemented methods that will help me (or methods that will not instantly compute when called, like pd.to_datetime). The csv file is 5 Gb when stored on disk and even though I only read a dozen of columns, it is far from being able to load into memory, so that's why I'm using Dask.

Would there be some sort of syntax that will just throw away "overflowed rows" (for instance something like : "with errors == ignore: ...") that I can apply to all my code, since I almost certain that is is the only error left after hours of debugging and that is due to very rare incoherent datetimes ?

```py
df= dd.read_csv('file', encoding = "ISO-8859-1" , engine='python', sep =";", skipinitialspace=True, dtype = object, blocksize =200e6, usecols = columns)

df["date"] = df["date"].astype('datetime64[D]')

df['number'] = df['number'].mask(condition, (pd.to_datetime('2019-10-01') - df['date']))

df['number'].value_counts().compute()
```

I have managed to narrow down the error to this particular substraction.
The overflow error is raised when running compute at the end, but it takes some time before the error is raised, and the calculation graph on the dashboard is already filled in half (nodes are released) when this happen. It is clear that it is caused by some values in the dataframe, but since I'm using dask and do not want to waste hours running calculations just to find those values, I'm requesting help in order to know if there is any bypass or "ignore method" to this problem.

Here is the error:

```
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-75db6e93c9a0> in <module>
----> 1 bdd['NbMois.Distribution'].value_counts().compute()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py in compute(self, **kwargs)
    154         dask.base.compute
    155         """
--> 156         (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
    157         return result
    158 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    395     keys = [x.__dask_keys__() for x in collections]
    396     postcomputes = [x.__dask_postcompute__() for x in collections]
--> 397     results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    398     return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
    399 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py in get(self, dsk, keys, restrictions, loose_restrictions, resources, sync, asynchronous, direct, retries, priority, fifo_timeout, actors, **kwargs)
   2319             try:
   2320                 results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous,
-> 2321                                       direct=direct)
   2322             finally:
   2323                 for f in futures.values():

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py in gather(self, futures, errors, maxsize, direct, asynchronous)
   1653             return self.sync(self._gather, futures, errors=errors,
   1654                              direct=direct, local_worker=local_worker,
-> 1655                              asynchronous=asynchronous)
   1656 
   1657     @gen.coroutine

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py in sync(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    671             return future
    672         else:
--> 673             return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
    674 
    675     def __repr__(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\utils.py in sync(loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
    275             e.wait(10)
    276     if error[0]:
--> 277         six.reraise(*error[0])
    278     else:
    279         return result[0]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\utils.py in f()
    260             if timeout is not None:
    261                 future = gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=timeout), future)
--> 262             result[0] = yield future
    263         except Exception as exc:
    264             error[0] = sys.exc_info()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py in run(self)
   1131 
   1132                     try:
-> 1133                         value = future.result()
   1134                     except Exception:
   1135                         self.had_exception = True

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py in run(self)
   1139                     if exc_info is not None:
   1140                         try:
-> 1141                             yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
   1142                         finally:
   1143                             # Break up a reference to itself

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py in _gather(self, futures, errors, direct, local_worker)
   1498                             six.reraise(type(exception),
   1499                                         exception,
-> 1500                                         traceback)
   1501                     if errors == 'skip':
   1502                         bad_keys.add(key)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    690                 value = tp()
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    693             raise value
    694         finally:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\compatibility.py in apply()
     91     def apply(func, args, kwargs=None):
     92         if kwargs:
---> 93             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     94         else:
     95             return func(*args)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\utils.py in partial_by_order()
    881     for i, arg in other:
    882         args2.insert(i, arg)
--> 883     return function(*args2, **kwargs)
    884 
    885 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper()
   1047 
   1048         if is_datetime64_dtype(left) or is_datetime64tz_dtype(left):
-> 1049             result = dispatch_to_index_op(op, left, right, pd.DatetimeIndex)
   1050             return construct_result(left, result,
   1051                                     index=left.index, name=res_name,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in dispatch_to_index_op()
   1099         left_idx = left_idx._shallow_copy(freq=None)
   1100     try:
-> 1101         result = op(left_idx, right)
   1102     except NullFrequencyError:
   1103         # DatetimeIndex and TimedeltaIndex with freq == None raise ValueError

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in rsub()
    115 
    116 def rsub(left, right):
--> 117     return right - left
    118 
    119 

pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._Timestamp.__sub__()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimelike.py in __sub__()
    898                 result = self._add_offset(-other)
    899             elif isinstance(other, (datetime, np.datetime64)):
--> 900                 result = self._sub_datelike(other)
    901             elif is_integer(other):
    902                 # This check must come after the check for np.timedelta64

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py in _sub_datelike()
    881                 i8 = self.asi8
    882                 result = checked_add_with_arr(i8, -other.value,
--> 883                                               arr_mask=self._isnan)
    884                 result = self._maybe_mask_results(result,
    885                                                   fill_value=libts.iNaT)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in checked_add_with_arr()
    965 
    966     if to_raise:
--> 967         raise OverflowError("Overflow in int64 addition")
    968     return arr + b
    969 

OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition
```

Comment: Hi tom.dupuis, welcome on SO. Please read something about [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](/help/mcve). Your example is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

A good chance is that your column `df['number']` is causing the problem.
Since you did not provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I tried to create one.

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd    
ddf = dask.datasets.timeseries()
ddf =ddf.reset_index()
ddf["date"] = ddf["timestamp"].astype('datetime64[D]')
ddf["number"] = ddf["date"].astype(int)
condition = ddf['timestamp']<'2000-01-01 00:00:04'
ddf['number'] = ddf['number'].mask(condition, (pd.to_datetime('2119-10-01') - ddf['date']))
ddf.head()
```

if you change the `pd.to_datetime('2119-10-01')` to `pd.to_datetime('2319-10-01')` you'll get a different error but it may be similar issue related to the date subtraction - [see other post - How to fix OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720783/how-to-fix-overflowerror-overflow-in-int64-addition)