# Issue with Overflow in int64 addition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56720783/6051639), only instead of subtracting 2 dates I am trying to add days to dates. I import the data from a csv and then convert `date` to datetime and `time` to a timedelta in days:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['days']=pd.to_timedelta(df['time'],'days')
```

The resulting dtypes are:

df.dtypes:

```
date               datetime64[ns]
days               timedelta64[ns]
```

My command is:

```
df['new_date']=df['date']+df['days']
```

The error I get is:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 69, in new_method
    return method(self, other)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 100, in __sub__
    return self._arith_method(other, operator.sub)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 5526, in _arith_method
    result = ops.arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 218, in arithmetic_op
    res_values = op(left, right)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 69, in new_method
    return method(self, other)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py", line 1330, in __sub__
    result = self._add_timedelta_arraylike(-other)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py", line 1126, in _add_timedelta_arraylike
    self_i8, other_i8, arr_mask=self._isnan, b_mask=other._isnan

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 1112, in checked_add_with_arr
    raise OverflowError("Overflow in int64 addition")

OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition
```

I can get it to work with the csv if turn my date into a (datetime) object first, as gleaned from the linked question:

```
obs['date']=pd.to_datetime(obs['date']).dt.date
```

df.dtypes:

```
days    timedelta64[ns]
date             object
```

But with this warning:

```
PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting object-dtype array to TimedeltaArray not vectorized
  PerformanceWarning,
```

Strangely I cannot reproduce the Overflow error when I create my own df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([range(1965,1970)]).T
df.columns=['year']
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df.year,format='%Y')
df['days']=pd.to_timedelta(30,'days')
df.dtypes
```

Note the dtypes are the same as those that give the Overflow error:

```
date    datetime64[ns]
days   timedelta64[ns]
```

Yet, the same command gives me exactly what I expect, rather than the Overflow error:

```
df['new_date']=df['date']+df['days']
```

df:

```
   year       date    days   new_date
0  1965 1965-01-01 30 days 1965-01-31
1  1966 1966-01-01 30 days 1966-01-31
2  1967 1967-01-01 30 days 1967-01-31
3  1968 1968-01-01 30 days 1968-01-31
4  1969 1969-01-01 30 days 1969-01-31
```

And if I make date a (datetime) object base on year:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['year']).dt.date
```

I get the PerformanceWarning again:

```
PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting object-dtype array to TimedeltaArray not vectorized
  PerformanceWarning,
```

This behavior seems inconsistent. I am struggling to figure out when I need `.dt.date` (i.e. the example when I read csv) and when I should not use it (i.e. performance warning. What is the best way to consistently handle datetime objects in pandas? Any help understanding what I am doing "wrong" would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply because I was tinkering and used the wrong symbol. I have confirmed the same behavior and corrected the question. Thanks!

Comment: `df['new_date'] = df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['days'], unit='d')`

Comment: Could you add an example how date and duration to be added look like in your input (as string)?